# How do I return more than one result from a function vba excel?

Tags: excel, vba, function, return, return-value

How do I return more than one result from a function vba?

```
Public Function test() As Integer
    test = 1, 2, 3
End Function
```

This gives a compile error.

How do I make this function return an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an array in this case

```
Option Explicit   
Public Sub PrintTest()
    Dim result() As Variant, i As Long

    result = test

    For i = LBound(result) To UBound(result)
        Debug.Print (result(i))
    Next

End Sub

Public Function test() As Variant
    test = Array(1, 2, 3)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively

```
Public Sub test(ByRef res1 as Integer, _
                ByRef res2 as Integer, _
                ByRef res3 as Integer)
    res1 = 1
    res2 = 2
    res3 = 3
Sub Function
```